# rspec expect to receive not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following class structure:

```
class A
  def process(processor)
    processor.process_x
  end
end

class Processor
  def process_x
  end
end
```

and the following test:

```
context "when process is called" do
  object_a = A.new
  processor = Processor.new

  it "calls processor.process_x" do
    object_a.process(processor)
    expect(processor).to receive(:process_x)
  end
end
```

but the test keeps failing. I even put a `byebug` and saw the processor's `process_x` method being called

how can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see my problem, after reading [this](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-with-rspec-doubles-and-expectations) I realized I should add the expectation first, then invoke the method:

```
context "when process is called" do
  object_a = A.new
  processor = Processor.new

  it "calls processor.process_x" do
    expect(processor).to receive(:process_x) *** HERE
    object_a.process(processor) *** HERE
  end
end
```